# Javascript regex to detect CSS code inside a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Parsing CSS in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326494/parsing-css-in-javascript-jquery)
>   [Parsing CSS string with RegEx in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412469/parsing-css-string-with-regex-in-javascript)

How can I find out if a string contains CSS rules?

Example rules:

```
selector {
  property:value;
}


selector { property:value; }

selector{property:value}

...
```

Basically I want to find out if a text block represents either PHP + HTML or CSS code.

One way to do this - I was thinking to trim the text, then match the first character of the text with `#`, `.` or a CSS selector such as `body`, `p` etc. DO you think it's a good idea?

Comment: [This](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-regular-expressions-for-efficient-web-development) article has a regex for pulling out CSS attributes. That may be modifiable to suit your purpose. The regex is: `\s(?[a-zA-Z-]+)\s[:]{1}\s*(?[a-zA-Z0-9\s.#]+)[;]{1}`

Comment: Not sure how concise this is, never having used it myself, but it looks promising... http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-regular-expressions-for-efficient-web-development

Comment: It's not a good idea to trim the text and try and match the selectors. You'd need to match the list of every HTML element out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr;** Consider using a proper CSS parser, such as [JSCSSP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/), for final validation.

*It depends on the goal and a regular expression might be entirely invalid.*

If this is just "attempting" to see if it "could" contain CSS selectors, then I might be inclined to try an overly-broad match, which will fail is there is anything complicated the CSS string values (like "}") or there are CSS comments, and will accept a wide range of input that is *not* valid CSS:

```
(?:\s*\S+\s*{[^}]*})+       // use anchored
```

Likewise, an expression that should detect *most* simple HTML (however invalid) with tags, and only unlucky cases of CSS (matches in comments or CSS strings or crazy child selectors):

```
<(?:br|p)[^>{]*>|</\w+\s*>   // use case-insensitive
```

Happy coding.

Also see: [Parsing CSS in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326494/parsing-css-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4064 might interest you.

> **Algorithmic Programming Language Identification**
>
> David Klein, Kyle Murray, Simon Weber
>
> (Submitted on 21 Jun 2011 (v1), last revised 9 Nov 2011 (this version, v2))
>
> Motivated by the amount of code that goes unidentified on the web, we introduce a practical method for algorithmically identifying the programming language of source code. Our work is based on supervised learning and intelligent statistical features. We also explored, but abandoned, a grammatical approach. In testing, our implementation greatly outperforms that of an existing tool that relies on a Bayesian classifier. Code is written in Python and available under an MIT license.